# Установка темной темы в приложении на Android. Android Studio

Tags: java, xml

Есть разметка(activity_main.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">
<Button
    android:id="@+id/BtnMain"
    android:text="@string/BtnLight"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="132dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="124dp"
    android:text="@string/sentence"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/BtnMain" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Код приложения:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private final String TAG = "MainActivity";
private Button button;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    button = findViewById(R.id.BtnMain);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (button.getText().toString().equals("LIGHT") && AppCompatDelegate.getDefaultNightMode() == AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES) {
                setTheme(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
                button.setText(R.string.BtnDark);
            }
            else {
                setTheme(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
                button.setText(R.string.BtnLight);
            }
            Log.d(TAG, "changed!");
        }
    });
}
```

}

Я хочу чтобы при нажатии кнопки тема переключалась со светлой темы на темную, и наоборот. Как это сделать? Я пробовал следующий код из моего Listener. Log выводится, но вот тема не меняется...

Comment: Вы просто устанавливаете тему, надо ещё перезагрузить activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Переключать темы с дневной на ночную можно с помощью обращения к `AppCompatDelegate`:

- Чтобы включить ночную тему:

  ```
  AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES)
  ```
- Чтобы переключить обратно на дневную тему:

  ```
  AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO)
  ```

Метод `setTheme()` работает в тех случаях, когда он вызывается после метода `super`, и перед `setContentView()` в методе `onCreate()`.

Comment: К сожалению, это не помогло мне

Comment: @Some_Body У вас довольно странное условие получается: вы проверяете, есть ли на кнопке нужная запись, и включена ли темная тема, и если включена, то все равно включаете темную тему.  Попробуйте убрать условие и проверить без него.